# How do I move my Dropbox folder on a headless Linux system?

Tags: linux, dropbox, headless

I am using a headless system with remote access only visa ssh. My file system is btrfs. To prepare for the upcoming ext4 shift, I created a ext4 image file -

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=dropbox.ext4.img bs=1M count=25600 conv=sync

sudo mkfs.ext4 dropbox.ext4.img

mkdir dropbox.ext4

sudo mount dropbox.ext4.img dropbox.ext4

dropbox stop

cd dropbox.ext4

sudo chown -R userme:groupme .

cp -R ~/Dropbox/* . && sync
```

Now I can either instruct the client to use the new folder for Dropbox, or rename Dropbox to Dropbox.old and re-mount dropbox.ext4.img at Dropbox.

I prefer the former. How do I do this from the terminal? I could not find instructions on doing this on the dropbox help site.

Are there any cons for the approach I am following with the ext4 container? The underlying filesystem is a btrfs RAID10.

Comment: Just a comment about `conv=sync` in your dd, info says it will "Pad every input block to size of ‘ibs’ with trailing zero bytes. When used with ‘block’ or ‘unblock’, pad with spaces instead of zero bytes.", it probably wouldn't matter using /dev/zero but for future dd use you probably want `fsync` instead... or don't bother and just do a `sync` in the terminal after dd's done.

Comment: Found this dropboxwiki.com page [Install Dropbox In An Entirely Text-Based Linux Environment - 3.1 Changing the dropbox folder location](https://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment#Changing_the_dropbox_folder_location), but it looks rather old, and uses scripts that are now dead links... so no luck